# Javascript is not working inside a accordion bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-accordion

I am using accordion tabs in my web application and in that I am facing an issue, each tab opens when i press the "Continue" button which is present in all the tabs.

Here the issue is, when I manually toggle from the 5th tab to the 4th tab and return to the 5th tab by pressing continue button, the Javascript scripts which are written in the 5th tab are completely not working. Even a simple alert() is not working. This happens only when we toggle the tabs manually.

Need help in fixing this. TIA

Comment: Show us some of your code to figure out what's happening

Comment: <input type="button" value="confirm order" id="button-confirm" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="loading..." />
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#button-confirm').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
   type: 'get',
   url: 'index.php?route=extension/payment/cod/confirm',
   cache: true,
   beforeSend: function() {
    $('#button-confirm').button('loading');
   },
   complete: function() {
    $('#button-confirm').button('reset');
   },
   success: function() {
    location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
   }
  });
 });
</script>

Comment: the above mentioned code is pulled from a external file into the 5th tab in the accordion tab.  
Now, the above mentioned code doesn't works when I manually toggle from the 5th tab to the 4th tab and return to the 5th tab by pressing continue button.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
  $(this).closest(".panel-default").find(".panel-collapse").removeClass("in");
  $(this).closest(".panel-default").next().find(".panel-collapse").addClass("in");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
  
   
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        Collapsible Group 1</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default button" value="continue"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
        Collapsible Group 2</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default button" value="continue2"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
        Collapsible Group 3</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default button" value="continue3"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i still face the same error.

Comment: When we press continue button on the 4th tab, the content which appears on the 5th tab are dynamically pulled from an external file using php ajax. The below mentioned code is used in the 5th tab.

Comment: <input type="button" value="confirm order" id="button-confirm" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="loading..." />
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#button-confirm').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
   type: 'get',
   url: 'index.php?route=extension/payment/cod/confirm',
   cache: true,
   beforeSend: function() {
    $('#button-confirm').button('loading');
   },
   complete: function() {
    $('#button-confirm').button('reset');
   },
   success: function() {
    location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
   }
  });
 });
</script>

Comment: Now, the above mentioned code doesn't works when I manually toggle from the 5th tab to the 4th tab and return to the 5th tab by pressing continue button.